# Android/Java/ Adding an Custom View to an GoogleMaps FragmentActivity

Tags: java, android, performance, android-fragments

Good evening !

Im currently trying to learn Java for android, and i already made some "Easy" apps. This time i want to create something more complex. I wanna try to draw Sprites or animations in an extra layer over google maps. I already know that i need Custom Views for that, but i dont know how to add that Custom View to the GoogleMaps FragmentActivity.

Heres my GoogleMaps activity :D :

```
public class GoogleMaps extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public Canvas c;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.google_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
}
```

And heres my Custom View :

```
public class SpriteLayer extends View {

Paint paint = new Paint();

public SpriteLayer(Context context) {
    super(context);


}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    Rect rect = new Rect(20, 56, 200, 112);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint );
}
}
```

So how do i add this CustomView to the GoogleMaps Fragment Activity to call the onDraw method ?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: is libgdx required for your requirement, everything is in native ?

Comment: Its native, but later I wanted to use libgdx for it. I didn't saw that I added that Tag :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android SDK already introduced [API](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) to create controller for specific part of the screen that can be easily re-used on multiple screens.

Libgdx can also be used as a part of a larger screen, inside a Fragment. Create a Libgdx fragment, subclass AndroidFragmentApplication and implement the onCreateView() with the following initialization:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return initializeForView(new MyGdxGame());
    }
```

That code depends on some other changes to the -android project:

1. Add Android V4 Support Library to the -android project and its build path if you haven't already added it. This is needed in order to Extend FragmentActivity later
2. Change AndroidLauncher activity to extend FragmentActivity, not AndroidApplication
3. Implement AndroidFragmentApplication.Callbacks on the AndroidLauncher activity
4. Create a Class that extends AndroidFragmentApplication which is the Fragment implementation for Libgdx.
5. Add the initializeForView() code in the Fragment's onCreateView method.
6. Finally, replace the AndroidLauncher activity content with the Libgdx Fragment.

Get more about fragmentation in libgdx :

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Starter-classes-%26-configuration#fragment-based-libgdx

Comment: That Sounds very good ! Thanks for your fast answer :) But how does it work, when i have a Google maps FragmentActivity and i want to Display libgdx Sprites on it ? Im gonna Test that when im Home ! Thanks again ^^